# How do I connect the Azure App service to the Local OnPremise Corporate network using ExpressRoute?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

My company has already established the ExpressRoute so my Corporate OnPremise network can access Azure resources internally.

Could someone please share the steps for me to connect the app service to Express Route so the Azure App Service can connect to the OnPremise SQL database?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the App Service VNET integration feature to access an Azure VNET resources from a web app. Then connect that VNET to your on-premises network with ExpressRoute and set up the correct traffic routing.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#access-on-premises-resources

Comment: thank you for the confirmation. So in this case do I need to plan for the downtime of the App Service or there is no downtime required?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I don't think I have seen that in the documentation, but I'm sure it will require, at least, a restart (so, a few minutes).

Comment: what about using this script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-an-app-in-Azure-ab7527e3 ? Will that Works integrating without an outage.